# Use Horizontal Scroll in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, epublib, monocle

I am currently using `epublib-core` to read epubs and display them in Android `WebView` with the following code -

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseURL, new String(spineReferences.get(chapter/* <- int*/).getResource().getData()), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

But it's using `Vertical Scroll` whereas I want a HorizontalScroll. After searching the web, I found [Monocle](http://monocle.inventivelabs.com.au/), but I don't know how to integrate `Monocle` with `epublib` and `WebView`. Any idea on how to use horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atlast, I could enable Horizontal Scroll in the app (without any Page Transitions). Use this code to scroll horizontally -

Create custom `WebViewClient` -

```
public class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {
private Context mContext;

public CustomWebClient(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    final MyWebView myWebView = (MyWebView) view;

    String varMySheet = "var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

    String addCSSRule = "function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
            + "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
            + "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"

            + "}";

    String insertRule1 = "addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: "
            + (myWebView.getMeasuredHeight() /  mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)
            + "px; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: "
            + myWebView.getMeasuredWidth() + "px;')";

    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + varMySheet);
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + addCSSRule);
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + insertRule1);

}
}
```

**Edit -**

I integrated epub lib with Monocle for nice effects, and here is the link to the whole source code - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8UizUpBrF1YX3UxcW5nLUVQMEk

Comment: what is MyWebView  ?

Comment: My custom WebView, not much different from the original WebView.

Comment: +InfinityChaos this method works but it does not give effect like turning pages and also images are breaking apart

Comment: I tried incorporating the page turning effect, but it did not look much good, so I scraped the idea. Incase you want to use it, see this - http://www.turnjs.com

Comment: there is this library which works fine but i am unable to integrate it https://github.com/joseph/Monocle ,  Finally did you give up the work or did you find any alternative?

Comment: Yeah I integrated Monocle with my app earlier, here is the link - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8UizUpBrF1YX3UxcW5nLUVQMEk   I completed the EPUB part of the app, but later abandoned it due to difficulty in support of other book formats.

Comment: i copied every thing from your classes and also copied all library in to assets folder but  it displays empty webview only error shown is  "Uncaught ReferenceError: Monocle is not defined", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Books/ (50)    , it is saying monocle is not defined where we are unzipping(i.e DownloadResource method location) the epuubfile what does that mean?

Comment: Please post the whole error, maybe I forgot to add the code to move the Monocle library from assets to Storage, and manually copied it. (I hadn't worked on that app for a long time).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LCQ9j  these are my phone screen and error in eclipse, i think that error is coming from some where inside monocle library

Comment: I checked the code on my phone, and Monocle was working fine with the same code. (From this, I mean the book was not shown, but the background Monocle shadows were there, probably some small bug). I have updated the Drive folder and added all code there with a pic of my Assets folder, check it again.

Comment: Also, check if `file:///android_asset/monocore.css` and `file:///android_asset/monocore.js` is present in BookData.java file, as this is used to make them read from Assets folder of app

Comment: ok i know now, you have modified your monocore.js mine just says //= require ./core/factory  .... etc and its only 1 kb and yours is 158 kb ,can you share your monocore.js file thanks in advance

Comment: Done, they're added to the Drive folder :) Actually, I think the original Monocore library has many different files, but I got this .js which compresses all of them into 1 file.

Comment: Thanks ,bro it works but it locks the sliding after click on screen and there is no text selection feature after adding ,i am a complete noob with javascript and dont want to get stuck in middle so i stated every thing from scratch in android way, Thanks for all the help you gave, that was the least i could give :)

Comment: Good luck for that!  A tip: The epubs are basically compressed HTML files,  so you can extract the text from it, and replace all image links with ImageViews instead of using WebView.

Answer (score 2):

To get horizontal pagination add `css` attribute to `html` before loading to `WebView`

```
String html = getBookContent();  // load epub content to String

int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width = (int) Math.floor(mWebView.getWidth() / density);
int height = (int) Math.floor(mWebView.getHeight() / density);

String style= "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1\"/>\n" +
     "<style type=\"text/css\">body {height: %heightpx; \n" + 
     "-webkit-column-width: %widthpx; -webkit-column-gap:0;}</style></head>";

html = html.replace("</head>", style);
html = html.replace("%width", String.valueOf(width));
html = html.replace("%height", String.valueOf(height));

 mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```