# Horizontal scrolling not smoothly and also with white space at bottom

Tags: javascript, android, webview, epub3

Iam trying to display a epub horizontally.It works but it does not scroll smoothly and even pagination is not set. How can i achieve it. Iam referring this link [Use Horizontal Scroll in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617345/use-horizontal-scroll-in-android-webview).